# Can I stop android from running updates while my activity?

Tags: android, performance

I have observed that my App has a good lag when Android runs an update of other Apps while my App runs, and the user interacts with the App. Sometimes, it takes 5 seconds to write data to the database which normally takes just 10 milliseconds. Is there a way to inform Android to run no updates and do similar tasks that need performance while a specific Activity of my App is in focus?

Comment: Don't think its possible to control Play Store from your app.

Comment: Maybe you could kill the proccess on a rooted device, but this would annoy the users. What about to pause YOUR app if it comes up? Maybe there is any broadcast send by google play if it runs updates.....

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this outside of the PlayStore app. The only way yo stop update Apps is go to the PlayMarket, open Settings, in General open Auto-update apps and set option Do not auto-update apps.